# Replacing variables in i18next

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-mobile, i18next

I have implemented i18next, and after getting help on a couple of issues all works fine.
I still have issues understanding parts of the documentation on the support site.

I'm trying to replicate this part (found [here](http://i18next.com/pages/doc_features.html)):

```
// given resources
{           
  'en-US': { translation: {  key: '__myVar__ are important' } }
};

i18n.t("key", { myVar: "variables" }); // -> variables are important
```

On my side of things, this is the JSON file:

```
{
    "app": {"name": "mytranslation" },
    "back": "Back",
    "cancel": "Cancel",
    "closemenu": "Close Menu",
    "closeoptions": "Close options",
    "currency": "Currency symbol is __currencysymbol__",
    "date": "Date",
    "description": "Description"
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div data-i18n="currency"></div>
    <script src="javascript/i18next-1.7.3.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        i18n.init({ preload: ['en', 'fr', 'ht', 'es', 'de', 'zh', 'vi', 'pt', 'it', 'th', 'dev'] });
        i18n.init({ detectLngQS: 'lang' });
        i18n.init(function(t) { 
            $("body").i18n();
            var appName = t("app.name");
        });
        i18n.t("currency", { currencysymbol: "$" }); //where do I place this code???
    </script>
</body>
```

Note: jQuery 2.1.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 are loaded in the header.

I'm sure I'm not placing the various parts where they are supposed to go, as it is not working (not inserting the variable "currencysymbol"). The rest of the code works fine, as I get all the translated text.

What I'd really like to achieve is to be able to create variables that would be called as part of the translations (currency symbol, company name, company address, etc... - for affiliates purposes), and be able to replace those values as they are repeated in the translated texts.

I would like to have those variables in one place, so they are easy to adjust, and they will not be subject to the context of language changes.

Answer (score 11):

Nowadays, you don't use `__this__` by default. You use `{{this}}`.

See this example:

```
{
    "key": "{{what}} is {{how}}"
}

i18next.t('key', { what: 'i18next', how: 'great' });
```

https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation

Prefix/Suffix for interpolation may be overridden though.

```
i18next.init({
  interpolation: { 
    prefix: "__",
    suffix: "__"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

In order for i18next to interpolate variables when calling the `i18n()` method against part of the DOM, you must:

- set the `useDataAttrOptions` option at init time
- provide the values of your variables in the `data-i18n-options` attribute of the targeted element

Your example HTML would become:

```
<body>
    <div data-i18n="currency"
         data-i18n-options='{"currencysymbol": "$"}'></div>
    <script src="javascript/i18next-1.7.3.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        i18n.init({
            preload: ['en', 'fr', 'ht', 'es', 'de', 'zh', 'vi', 'pt', 'it', 'th', 'dev'],
            detectLngQS: 'lang',
            useDataAttrOptions: true
        }, function(t) {
            $("body").i18n();
            var appName = t("app.name");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**Note:** The options are a JSON object, therefore proper quoting is essential. In the code above, the value of the `data-i18n-options` attribute is written between simple quotes for the sake of readability. But as a matter of taste, convenience, or masochism, your may opt for either of the following, also valid HTML options:

- unquoted: `data-i18n-options={"currencysymbol":"$"}`
- double-quoted with HTML entities: `data-i18n-options="{&quot;currencysymbol&quot;: &quot;$&quot;}"`
- double-quoted with numeric entities: `data-i18n-options="{&#34;currencysymbol&#34;: &#34;$&#34;}"`